# Visual Studio 2013 debugging does not start after installing WebMatrix

Tags: visual-studio-2013, webmatrix, visual-studio-debugging

Yesterday i installed WebMatrix on my computer. The install did not complete successfully and I ended up uninstalling the program. Now VS2013 will not start the debugger.

What happens is that I select a project, click "Start Debugging" and then the debugger just exits without any exceptions and the browser displaying the error message "Server not found", or (sometimes) I get the error message "Process with an Id of XXXX is not running".

I've tried to run "repair" on IIS Express 8, but it did not help.
How can I make VS2013 start the debugger again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out after two days of trubleshooting. [This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/finbar_ryan/archive/2013/01/02/debugging-the-unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server-error-from-visual-studio-2012.aspx) helped me solve the problem.

> It turns out that [WebMatrix] adds a new REG_SZ value called
>   CustomUserHome at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\IISExpress.
>   This points to the Web Matrix Config file and not the IIS Express one.

I deleted the key `CustomUserHome` and now everything works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than fixing the problem, can you do a "system restore" to prior to the install of webMatrix?  A windows system restore puts the installed software and registry back to a particular point in time without interfering with your own data.  To do a system restore follow the steps in this microsoft guide:   http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/restore-system-files-and-settings.

Comment: What do you mean by a "system restore"? I'm working on my work pc and it has some restrictions that makes Webmatrix fail during installation.

Comment: i expanded on my answer.   I'm guessing you are an admin on your own machine since you were able to attempt installing WebMatrix.  Good luck.

Comment: "system restore is disabled by your system administrator" :(